# How to build static lib without ARC for a project which uses ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, static-libraries

How can I build a static lib without ARC for a project which uses ARC?

I found some source for a static lib, I want build it for my project but I use ARC.

Comment: just build and use, the lib doesn't care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static library can be built without ARC and included in your project with ARC without doing anything special. If you want to add the source directly, you'll need to add the following compilation option to each non-arc file in build phases: `-fno-objc-arc`.

Answer (score 0):

In general case : You can opt for few files(static lib) not using ARC and your own files using ARC.

But for lib it is not required.

[You can merge ARC and Non-ARC files quite simply](http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html), however you have compiled lib then it doesn't care.

Comment: Static libraries do not need to be attributed as "not using ARC" or alike. This answer is at least confusing (as the first sentence implies that a static lib would need such exclusion).

Comment: @Till: Sorry for my bad english.